# C# - Read the content of PDF(form based) in the form of text

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, itext

I have one PDF which is editable(Form based/XFA). I need to get it's content in the form of text. What I have tried using `iTextSharp.text.pdf` is -

```
        var reader = new PdfReader(path);
        if (reader.AcroFields.Xfa.XfaPresent)
        {
            AcroFields af = reader.AcroFields;
            foreach (var item in af.Fields)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", item.Key, item.Value);                        
            }
        }
```

But by using this, I am not getting any content of that PDF file. Please Help.

> Please find the sample PDF related to this question at - 
>   https://sendeyo.com/en/2f25e157a4
>
> > Use Adobe Reader in your system to view the proper content of this
> >     file.

Comment: @Bruno - No problem. You have given me the exact direction, which helped me to solve the issue. Thanks.